# Android listview layout optimisation

Tags: android, listview, layout

When creating a listview layout, is it advisable to keep the layouts as simple as possible with relative layouts and minimal images and text, or is it ok to make them a little fancier with a couple of buttons, possibly an image or two, and some text within  tablelayouts?

I am trying to minimise the clicks/touches to get to the pertinent information, and giving the user a nicer UI to play with as opposed to a bog standard list.

I've tried to research it but cant find guidlines on design layout and limitations on listviews.

Something tells me the xml below is the cause of the choking the listview experiences if the resultset grows to more than say 20?

Thank you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/White" android:gravity="center">
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <ImageView android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_marginTop="4px" android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_height="60dip" android:src="@drawable/indian" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"></ImageView>
            <TableLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:id="@+id/title" android:textSize="18dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLines="10" android:layout_gravity="left" android:focusable="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@+id/label"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:textColor="@color/Black" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/distanceText" android:textSize="12dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="left" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="15dip">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout3" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow8" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/introImage" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitStart" android:paddingLeft="8dip"></ImageView>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:linksClickable="true" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false" android:text="more" android:autoLink="all" android:textColorLink="@color/Aqua" android:textSize="12dip" android:clickable="true" android:paddingRight="5dip" android:id="@+id/intro" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/description" android:text="description" android:visibility="invisible" android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="12dip" android:autoLink="all" android:clickable="true" android:linksClickable="true" android:textColorLink="@color/DarkGray"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/listviewmenu" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center">
            <Button android:id="@+id/mapClick" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/map_info" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/actionbutton" android:textColor="@color/White" android:textColorHighlight="@color/AntiqueWhite" android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/moreClick" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/more_info" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/White" android:textColorHighlight="@color/Aqua" android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/actionmore"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Picked up some very good info here: [Romain Guy][1]


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the same layout but use only one `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_frame" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/introImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/introImage"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="more"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/intro"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:text="description"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="map_info"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/moreClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="more_info"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just changed `color`, `string` and `drawable` references to see if it works!

**`RelativeLayout` rulez!**

Comment: I left the last `LinearLayout` only because is has a background otherwise you can remove it, too. 
Another thing: don't use **px**, use instead **dp**.

Comment: brilliant, absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to keep the layouts of the `ListView` items simple - and by that I mean fast performing. Simple does not mean boring :)

`RelativeLayout`s are best for rows of a `ListView` since they require only one pass to render, as opposed to say, nested `LinearLayout`s (as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)). However, if you must go beyond the simple and include a bit of fancy stuff in your rows, there are a couple of tricks provided by the platform to help you.

1. Use the `convertView` optimization - i.e, in the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`, check to see if the `convertView` parameter is null. If it isn't then just use that object, and modify it with new values instead of inflating a new one.
2. Even if you use option 1 above, use the `ViewHolder` pattern to not only avoid inflation; but also optimize the "modifying the row with new values" step. This is described in [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA).

Comment: just needed to hear it from someone in the know. thank you for a clear explanation.